# Advice on active line-level audio mixer using a single supply rail

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, single-supply-op-amp, mixer

A few years ago a asked a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498935/simple-stereo-audio-mixer-power-supply/) about an active audio (line level) mixer I wanted to make. I got some advice about how to run it off a single supply to make things easier and I was hoping to come back to this project and build the thing properly.

I am trying to make this thing "quality", in that it will have decent noise rejection and amplify the inputs cleanly. It doesn't need to be audiophile grade but just something good. To that end, I have tried to scour the net for some example schematics and I have built something that I think should work OK. I had some questions, however, mostly pertaining to a comment from Marcus Müller about low-pass filtering and other bits.

Firstly, my schematic:

[image: Single Supply Mixer - Preliminary Design]

Now for my questions:

- Are there any obvious rookie mistakes here? I have built similar circuits in the past that work OK, but that could be more by luck than judgment.
- Do I have the correct bypass caps here? I tried to follow the datasheets for the ICs closely, but it's not always clear if you need 100nF caps on the inputs of everything.
- Marcus (in my previous post) mentioned that I could put LPFs on the inputs of the op-amps. I am not quite sure how to implement this... Should I put caps to ground after each of R1 - R8? Or maybe just one cap per mixed channel after C6 and C8? Do I even need C6 and C8?
- Can I even add active LPFs? Maybe with extra op-amps, or can I change the first buffer stage (with unity gain) into a LPF?
- Am I using `Vref` correctly? I assume that the decoupling caps for the op-amps are referenced to "proper" ground and not the virtual ground?
- Marcus also suggested some good power filtering. I have decided to use an LDO here since I thought it would work well - do I also need some filtering components on the power input? Is the LDO OK with just the "raw" power from the 6V switching wall-supply?

Please feel free to offer improvements.

Comment: Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: @Andyaka no not yet. I will try and see what happens. To be honest though I'm not sure I know exactly what I am looking for in the output so some help here would also be appreciated.

Comment: You are looking to see whether it functions. Then, you ask questions if needs be.

Comment: OK so I have simulated the circuit. It seems I understand the Vref part correctly and I get the correct output. However, the simulation doesn't really answer my questions about how to implement thr LPFs and the bypassing/filtering. Can anyone help with these points?

Comment: You need to produce spectral responses that show whether your filtering is cutting the mustard. Post them.